# How to group data with date string inside subdocuments under an array mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document have this structure

```
_id: "adklkj389723jk23KLJjl2LU92kJO387"
"impressions": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("5b74799535f2722494075981"),
    "country": "GB",
    "impression_count": 22,
    "_campaignid": ObjectId("5b72d78847db422040ee60cf"),
    "date": ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b74799d35f2722494075982"),
    "country": "GB",
    "impression_count": 22,
    "_campaignid": ObjectId("5b72d7bf47db422040ee60d1"),
    "date": ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5b7479a735f2722494075983"),
    "country": "GB",
    "impression_count": 20,
    "_campaignid": ObjectId("5b72d79e47db422040ee60d0"),
    "date": ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z")
  }
]
```

**What i want to do** 
I want to group impressions with dates on which they are created where i am saving date as string in db to do this I am using this query

```
db.advertisers.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$impressions.date",
    count: {
      $sum: "$impressions.impression_count"
    }
  }
}]).pretty()
```

***Result***

This query is giving me the result like so what am i doing wrong ?

```
{
  "_id": [
    ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z"),
    ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z"),
    ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z")
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with an array you might want to `unwind` the `impressions`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$impressions"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$impressions.date",
      count: {
        $sum: "$impressions.impression_count"
      },

    }
  }
])
```

This would give you:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z"),
    "count": 64
  }
]
```

You can [see this here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bywGqv8OXSH).

Comment: Thank you so much it worked i am so stupid i had seen that in different tutorials and understand the concept but never tried, don't know why i wasted my two days

Comment: No worries. It happens to all of us :)

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get the output based on match date, let say i only want to see the results of 2018-08-15

Comment: You can add `between` the $unwind and $group a `$match` like this:  `{$match: {"impressions.date": ISODate("2018-08-15T19:00:00Z")}}` or any other `$match` logic

Comment: Oh.. great what is the purpose of adding it after $unwind I was adding match at start but did not get any result